# Change zookeeper log directory in Embedded Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am setting up Embedded-Kafka for JUnit test in my application which is using spring Kafka. What is the location/property to set for zookeeper log directory.
When using Embedded-Kafka, I don't have file named server.properties or zookeeper.properties
By Default, it creates log files in temp folder on Windows, but my temp windows is restrictive so I get an exception

I was able to specify the Kafka log directory by using following

```
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = { "log.dirs=../kafka-logs/" })
```

For broker/zookeeper properties I tried -

```
 static {
  props.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "../kafka-logs/");
}
```

Comment: It should read "log.dir" and not "log.dirs".

Comment: which class are you setting this property java.io.tmpdir? have you created custom EmbeddedZookeeper as well?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `java.io.tmpdir` works fine for me.

```
../kafka/kafka-1090602028141584277
```

(`../kafka` must exist already).

Perhaps your `static` block is invoked after the `EmbeddedZookeeper` is created?

Comment: How to Check for that ?

Comment: In a debugger? Set a breakpoint there and in `EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet()` which is where the `EmbeddedZookeeper` is created.